# prevent uicollectionview section starting on new line

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I'm using a flow layout on uicollectionview. It all looks great except it seems to start another section on another line. This seems like a sensible default but how do I override this and make the sections flow seamlessly on the same line as if no new section began?

Thanks!

Comment: put your bunch of code ..

Comment: Everything is default. new UICollectionViewFlowLayout, new UICollectionView... this just is a question about stopping the sections from going on the new line

Answer (score 2):

There is a library I found which has this as one of its features

RDHCollectionViewGridLayout

https://github.com/rhodgkins/RDHCollectionViewGridLayout